# Submit button is enabled when Angular form is not valid

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I have a search form that is invalid by default, because it requires some data to have. And because a form is invalid I also disable a submit button:

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="search()">
     <input
        formControlName="number"
        type="search"
        required>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="searchForm.invalid">Search</button>
</form>
```

I am trying test that submit button is disabled, but in my test cases button is not disabled even if search form is invalid.

```
const submitButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button[type="submit"]'));
console.log(submitButton.nativeElement.disabled);
console.log(component.searchForm.invalid);
```

These `console.log`s give me:

```
LOG: false
LOG: true
```

So this is my test case:

```
describe('SearchComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchFormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchFormComponent>;

  const searchParams = Object.freeze({});

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
      declarations: [ SearchFormComponent ],
      providers: [
        FormBuilder,
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { 'queryParams': Observable.of(searchParams) } },
        { provide: Router, useValue: jasmine.createSpy('navigate') }
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  const updateForm = (control, value) => component.searchForm.controls[control].setValue(value);

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
  });

  fit(`should disable a search button`, () => {
    const submitButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button[type="submit"]'));
    console.log(submitButton.nativeElement.disabled);
    console.log(component.searchForm.invalid);
  });

});
```

Why is it happen and how to fix that?